# Is it possible to parse protobuf binary using descriptorpb.DescriptorProto

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

The use case is parsing idls in service A and parsing protobuf messages to json in service B.

1. Using jhump.protoreflect to parse idl and get desc.MessageDescriptor, then use protojson to marshal descriptorpb.DescriptorProto

   h, _ := protojson.Marshal(md.Descriptor.AsDescriptorProto())
2. Using protojson to unmarshal h and get DescriptorProto

   var z descriptorpb.ç
   if err := protojson.Unmarshal(h, &z); err != nil {
   fmt.Println(err.Error())
   }
3. How to parse message by using DescriptorProto?

If I'm doing the whole work in the same service, I'm able to parse the message by using MessageDescriptor

```
dm := dynamic.NewMessage(md)
dm.Unmarshal(body)
dm.MarshalJSONPB(&jsonpb.Marshaler{OrigName: true, EnumsAsInts: true})
```

but the issue is parsing message is done in a different service, so I'm looking to keep some "message descriptor" in database and can be used by service B.

Any suggestion?